# Animating sprites at different speed than what the game runs at

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, platformer

I am building a Javascript/canvas platformer game, and it's coming along nicely. The only problem I've really run into where I can think of any solution at all is the animation of my player sprite.

The game loop is running every 16ms, which equates to 60fps. On every game loop, I'm using a method of my player class (called draw) to draw the player sprite. The sprite looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/THlGX.png

On every call of the draw method, I am advancing the "frame" of the player sprite, to give the illusion that the player is moving. As far as I know, this is common practice. However, due to my draw method being run every 16ms with the game loop, my player sprite is animating extremely quickly, and it doesn't look realistic at all.

Is there a way to slow this down to a pre-defined speed, or will I have to resort to adding loads of duplicate frames to my player sprite? Obviously that's not a great solution, as to make it look realistic at a game speed of 60fps I'd need to have a LOT of frames.

Here's my relevant code:

```
// Sets off the main game loop
setInterval("gameLoop()", gameSpeed);

function gameLoop() {
    // Updates
    player.update();

    // Draw
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    player.draw();
}

// Then in my player class...

this.draw = function() {
        if(this.state == "idle") {
            c.drawImage(this.idleSprite, this.idleSprite.frameWidth * this.idleSprite.frameCount, 0, this.idleSprite.frameWidth, this.idleSprite.frameHeight, this.xpos, this.ypos, this.idleSprite.frameWidth, this.idleSprite.frameHeight);
            if(this.idleSprite.frameCount < this.idleSprite.frames - 1) { this.idleSprite.frameCount++; } else { this.idleSprite.frameCount = 0; }
        } else if(this.state == "running") {
            var height = 0;
            if(this.facing == "left") { height = 37; }
            c.drawImage(this.runningSprite, this.runningSprite.frameWidth * this.runningSprite.frameCount, height, this.runningSprite.frameWidth, this.runningSprite.frameHeight, this.xpos, this.ypos, this.runningSprite.frameWidth, this.runningSprite.frameHeight);
            if(this.runningSprite.frameCount < this.runningSprite.frames - 1) { this.runningSprite.frameCount++; } else { this.runningSprite.frameCount = 0; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I always do in this case is store a `frameTime` variable and store the last update time variable inside my animation class. Then I only update the frame if the `currentTime - lastUpdateTime > frameTime`, in which case I also set last update time to `currentTime`.

Huzzah for animation =]

Comment: @Andy, I do the same thing as ultifinitus, Except that do `lastUpdateTime = lastUpdateTime + frametime` so as to not lose time. If you simply set the `lastUpdateTime = currentTime`, your animation's speed will vary just a little bit. Probably not noticeable in most cases, but if you need to predict exactly when a long animation will end, you don't want to lose time.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try to use a new timer for the player, just a timeout for the next animation and in case of bad things the gameloop can clear this timer and reset the player.